# python declaration of constant beginning with number

Tags: python, conventions

I have a python module with definitions of constants. They look like so:

```
30KHZ = 0b000
125KHZ = 0b001
250KHZ = 0b010
1MHZ = 0b011
```

Obviously, these are not allowed names. One way of to deal with this is to prepend names with something. Names like `_30KHZ` look nice, but they mess with static analyzers. Names like `S_30KHZ` or `F30KHZ` are allowed, but they look awkward and the meaning of the `S_` or `F` may be unclear.
Another way is to rotate the name like so: `KHZ30`. But is doesn't look good either.

How to name such constants to make their meaning obvious to the user?

Comment: Since these appear to be frequencies, I would opt for the longer name `freq_30khz` and so on. [explicit is better than implicit](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/).

Comment: Better yet, are the exact frequencies important, or does the user just need to know that these are, for instance, low, medium, high, and very high frequencies?

Comment: I would say FREQ_30HZ, using capital letters and underscores only for [constants](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#constants).

Comment: @chepner there are about a dozen of those

Comment: As an alternative way can you use dict for this constants?

Comment: @VitaliyVolkov Theoretically yes, but I've never seen a module exporting constants in a dict

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably put these in a dictionary:

```
BITMAPS = {
    "30KHZ": 0b000,
    "125KHZ": 0b001,
    "250KHZ": 0b010,
    "1MHZ": 0b011,
}
```

Comment: arguably even better `bitmaps = {30: 0b000, 125: 0b001, 250: 0b010, 1000: 0b011}` then you can just access using their value.

Comment: For some reason when I think about constants in python, I think "dot notation"

Comment: @Sergey: sure. In this case, however, you can't use dot notation since the keys are numbers (or being with numbers), so you have to do something different.